# boosting query, copied from documentation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create boosting query like its shown in [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-boosting-query.html)
but when I try

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all":{}
  },
  "boosting": {
    "positive": {
      "term": {
        "is_job_seeking": 1
      }
    },
    "negative": {
      "term": {
        "is_job_seeking": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "negative_boost" : 0.2
}
```

its not working I'm getting error

```
error: SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;
        shardFailures {[bP7jZnVHSRu83G30B0uSmw][idx_users_all_backup_dev][0]: 
        SearchParseException[[idx_users_all_backup_dev][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
        Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
          {
            "boosting": {
              "positive": {
                "term": {
                  "field1":"value1"
                }
              },
              "negative": {
                "term": {
                  "field2":"value2"
                }
              },
              "negative_boost":0.2
            }
          }
        ]]];
        nested: SearchParseException[[idx_users_all_backup_dev][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
        Parse Failure [No parser for element [boosting]]]; }{[bP7jZnVHSRu83G30B0uSmw][idx_users_all_backup_dev][1]: 
        SearchParseException[[idx_users_all_backup_dev][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
        Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
          {
            "boosting": {
              "positive": {
                "term": {
                  "field1":"value1"
                }
              },
              "negative": {
                "term": {
                  "field2":"value2"
                }
              },
              "negative_boost":0.2
            }
          }  
        ]]]; 
        nested: SearchParseException[[idx_users_all_backup_dev][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
        Parse Failure [No parser for element [boosting]]]; }{[bP7jZnVHSRu83G30B0uSmw][idx_users_all_backup_dev][2]: 
        SearchParseException[[idx_users_all_backup_dev][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
        Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
          {
            "boosting": {
              "positive": {
                "term": {
                  "field1":"value1"
                }
              },
              "negative": {
                "term": {
                  "field2":"value2"
                }
              },
              "negative_boost":0.2
            }
          }
        ]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[idx_users_all_backup_dev][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
        Parse Failure [No parser for element [boosting]]]; }{[bP7jZnVHSRu83G30B0uSmw][idx_users_all_backup_dev][3]: 
        SearchParseException[[idx_users_all_backup_dev][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
        Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
          {
            "boosting": {
              "positive": {
                "term": {
                  "field1":"value1"
                }
              },
              "negative": {
                "term": {
                  "field2":"value2"
                }
              },
              "negative_boost":0.2
            }
          }
        ]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[idx_users_all_backup_dev][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
        Parse Failure [No parser for element [boosting]]]; }{[bP7jZnVHSRu83G30B0uSmw][idx_users_all_backup_dev][4]: 
        SearchParseException[[idx_users_all_backup_dev][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
        Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
          {
            "boosting": {
              "positive": {
                "term": {
                  "field1":"value1"
                }
              },
              "negative": {
                "term": {
                  "field2":"value2"
                }
              },
              "negative_boost":0.2
            }
          }
        ]]]; 
        nested: SearchParseException[[idx_users_all_backup_dev][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: 
        Parse Failure [No parser for element [boosting]]]; }]
status: 400
```

I also try to add `explain: true` but it doesn't give me any extra information about what's wrong with query.

**Edit**
I have written such query

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "is_active": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "fields": [
    "is_job_seeking", "is_active"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "term": {
                "is_job_seeking": 1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "boosting": {
            "positive": {
              "term": {
                "is_active": 1
              }
            },
            "negative": {
              "term": {
                "is_active": 0
              }
            },
            "negative_boost": 0.3
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and this query give me 1000 results but there is no documents with `is_active=0`, when I remove `boosting` section I correct results with documents `is_active=0`

Comment: As per Andrei's answer the boost needs to be part of the query. There's a better documentation example at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/not-quite-not.html#boosting-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "boosting": {
      "positive": {
        "term": {
          "is_job_seeking": 1
        }
      },
      "negative": {
        "term": {
          "is_job_seeking": 0
        }
      },
      "negative_boost": 0.2
    }
  }
}
```

With `bool`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "text": {
              "value": "something"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "boosting": {
            "positive": {
              "term": {
                "is_job_seeking": 1
              }
            },
            "negative": {
              "term": {
                "is_job_seeking": 0
              }
            },
            "negative_boost": 0.2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And how I can now add some bool query in it ??

Comment: can You please look at my first post I have add some code

Comment: I'd suggest creating another question, this isn't quite related with what you asked initially.